# The newest version of RStudio refuse to let me install "Numbers" package. What should I do?

Tags: r, version, updates, r-package

I originally want to use R-Swat for work and I followed the instruction to install R-Swat. It asked me to add install package "numbers"

```
> runGitHub("R-SWAT","tamnva")
Downloading https://github.com/tamnva/R-SWAT/archive/HEAD.tar.gz
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘sensitivity’ in loadNamespace(i, c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[i]]):
 there is no package called ‘numbers’
type here
```

Then I decide to use the code to install package "numbers" with the following code:

```
> install.packages("numbers")
```

Here is the result:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/Victor/Documents/R/win-library/4.0’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘numbers’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
Warning in install.packages :
  unable to access index for repository https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/4.0:
  cannot open URL 'https://www.stats.ox.ac.uk/pub/RWin/bin/windows/contrib/4.0/PACKAGES'
```

I tried to look up online by following the feedback of RStudio, but I can't find any equivalent of 'numbers' package, for my RStudio (2023.03.0-daily+82.pro2)

- Please let me know what equivalent of "numbers" package I should install for my RStudio so that I can use R-SWAT. Thank you.

I tried to look up online and find the newest version of "numbers" package but i can't find anything.

Comment: `numbers` is a listed package on CRAN and requires R > v4.1.0. You need to update your R installation (not RStudio), 4.0 is a few years old now.